# Typescript types for a hook that returns a piece of the Redux state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, typescript-typings

I have this hook named `useReduxState` which I use to retrieve a piece of state from Redux by doing:

```
const STATE_A = useReduxState("STATE_A");
```

And I'm having trouble while adding Typescript to it.

These are the types that I'm working with:

```
type TYPE_A = {
  fooA: string,
  barA: string,
}

type TYPE_B = {
  fooB: string,
  barB: string
}

interface REDUX_STATE {
  STATE_A: TYPE_A,
  STATE_B: TYPE_B,
}
```

And this is the code for the hook (it uses the `useSelector` hook from the `react-redux` package);

```
function useReduxState(STATE_NAME: REDUX_STATE_KEYS): REDUX_STATE_VALUES {
  
  const STATE = useSelector((state: REDUX_STATE) : REDUX_STATE_VALUES => state[STATE_NAME]);
  return STATE;

}
```

My goal is to be able to write something as:

```
const { fooA, barA } = useReduxState("STATE_A");
```

And I want Typescript to know that I can access those two properties `fooA and barA` because they are present in `TYPE_A` which is the type for the `STATE_A`.

But I'm getting these errors:

```
Property 'fooA' does not exist on type 'REDUX_STATE_VALUES'.ts(2339)
Property 'barA' does not exist on type 'REDUX_STATE_VALUES'.ts(2339)
```

Here is the type `REDUX_STATE_VALUES`

[image]

It seems correct, but I want Typescript to know that when I pass `"STATE_A"` as an argument, the return type should be `TYPE_A`, so I can access its properties `fooA and barA`. And vice-versa for `"STATE_B"` and its type.

How can I achieve that? Should I be using generics in this case to be able to get this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would need a generic so that each call to your function will determine which field it is accessing:

```
function useReduxState<K extends keyof REDUX_STATE>(STATE_NAME: K): REDUX_STATE[K] {
```

the argument will be one `keyof REDUX_STATE` and the return type will be the corresponding value, so when you are passed a specific string it will figure out the correct return type.

you will also need to remove the explicit return annotation on your function, it will infer the correct type from usage and you need more specific than `REDUX_STATE_VALUES`

```
useSelector((state: REDUX_STATE) => state[STATE_NAME])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Really helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using TypeScript interfaces to map the objects TYPE_A and TYPE_B.

```
export interface TypeA {
   fooA: string;
   barA: string
}

export interface TypeB {
    fooB:string;
    barB: string
}
```

In your ReduxState interface file import the TypeA and TypeB interfaces

```
export interface ReduxState {
   Type_A: TypeA;
   Type_B: TypeB;
```

}

Comment: Thanks, but this was not the answer I was looking for.